# over_voltage possible values

Tags: config.txt

Does anyone know this configuration 'over_voltage':

- What does it do?
- How can I configure it? (using config.txt and write the value?)
- What are possible values?
- What is the difference between it and  'over_voltage_avs'?

I found this configuration by chance when running

```
 vcgencmd get_config
```

I hope also if someone has good resource about other voltage/current configuration for raspberry.

For example, I found by chance also that voltage can be detected by running `vcgencmd measure_volts <unit_name>`
with unit name as: core, sdram_c, sdram_i, sdram_p.

So does anyone know if we can measure volts of usb interface?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Over-voltage is not related to USB, which is required by the spec to always be at 4.75V..5.25V. It's about voltage applied to different high-speed parts of the chip like CPU or video hardware.

Answer (score 8):

The permitted over voltage values are given in 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/README.md

> CPU/GPU core voltage adjustment. [-16,8] equates to [0.8V,1.4V] with
>   0.025V steps; in other words, specifying -16 will give 0.8V as the GPU/core voltage, and specifying 8 will give 1.4V. The default value
>   is 0 (1.2V). Values above 6 are only allowed when force_turbo or
>   current_limit_override are specified; this sets the warranty bit.

To summarise

```
over_voltage=-16 # 0.8V
over_voltage=0   # 1.2V
over_voltage=8   # 1.4V
```

Comment: New URL: https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#overclocking
Also note that `0` means 1.35V on newer models, being 1.2V only on RPi 1.

Answer (score 0):

Up to 1.55v now on the rpi 5. Also run

```
$  vcgencmd pmic_read_adc EXT5V_V
```

To monitor supply voltage on the v5.